# Estimations of some new recurrence sequences

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, recursion, laurent-series

> *Problem 1*. Given the recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \sqrt{a_{n}^{2}+ a_{n}}$ with $a_{1}= 1.$ Prove that
> $$a_{n}\sim\frac{n}{2}+ \frac{1}{2n}\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$

For *problem 1*, I only can prove $a_{n}\sim\left ( n+ 1 \right )/2$ by using the Laurent series for the increasing $a_{n} :$
$$a_{n+ 1}= a_{n}+ \dfrac{1}{2}+ \mathcal{O}\left ( \dfrac{1}{a_{n}} \right )$$

> *Problem 2*. Given the recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \sqrt[3]{a_{n}^{3}+ a_{n}}$ with $a_{1}= 1.$ Prove that
> $$a_{n+ 1}\sim\sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{3}}\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$
> What if we changed the given one by $a_{n+ 1}= \sqrt[3]{a_{n}^{3}+ 3a_{n}^{2}+ a_{n}}$ ?

For *problem 2*, similarly, I saw that $a_{n+ 1}\fallingdotseq a_{n}+ \dfrac{1}{3a_{n}}$, then how can we find the relative equations like ${y}'= \dfrac{1}{3y}$ by $n$ times ?

Comment: For 1, try the recursion for $b_n=a_n+\frac12$

Comment: Copy that, sir.

Comment: Help me@RiverLi

Comment: @hd_30102 Many users will help you. I will try as well.

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Comment: The 2 problems are interesting. How do you get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use the approach in [1].

For Problem 1:

First, clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$.

Second, we have
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} - a_n &= \sqrt{a_n^2 + a_n} - a_n\\
&= a_n\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{a_n}} - 1\right)\\
&= a_n\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{a_n} 
+ o\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right) - 1\right)\\
&\to \frac{1}{2},\quad \mathrm{as}\ n\to \infty.
\end{align}
Thus, $a_n \sim \frac{n}{2}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Third, we have
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} - a_n &= \sqrt{a_n^2 + a_n} - a_n\\
&= a_n\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{a_n}} - 1\right)\\
&= a_n\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{a_n^2}
+ o\left(\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right) - 1\right)\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{a_n}, \quad \mathrm{as}\ n\to \infty\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4n}, \quad \mathrm{as}\ n\to \infty.
\end{align}
Thus, $a_n \sim \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\ln n$ as $n\to \infty$.

$\phantom{2}$

For problem 2:

First, clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$.

Second, we have
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2 &= (\sqrt[3]{a_n^3 + a_n})^2 - a_n^2 \\
&= a_n^2 \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)^{2/3} - 1\right)\\
&= a_n^2 \left(1 + \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{a_n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right) - 1\right)\\
&\to \frac{2}{3}, \quad \mathrm{as}\ n\to \infty.
\end{align}
Thus, $a_n^2 \sim \frac{2}{3}n$ as $n\to \infty$.
Thus, $a_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}n}$ as $n\to \infty$.

*Reference*

[1] "The second term in asymptotic expansion", by Moubinool OMARJEE, Paris

Comment: This technique is beautiful!

Comment: @hd_30102 Your question is interesting.

Comment: @haidangel For example, use Stirling’s formula to deal with $\ln n!$.

Comment: @haidangel Or use Stolz-Cesaro theorem.