# Find the $\mathcal{o}\left(n\right)$ so that $a_n\sim\frac{\mathcal{o}\left(n\right)}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right){\rm as}\lim a_n=\infty$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, recursion, laurent-series

> Given a recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \dfrac{1}{2}\left ( a_{n}+ \dfrac{1}{a_{n}} \right )$ with $a_{1}> 0.$ Find the $\mathcal{o}\left ( n \right )$ so that
> $$a_{n}\sim\frac{\mathcal{o}\left ( n \right )}{n}+ \mathcal{O}\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$

*Remark*. The original one is proving $\lim a_{n}= 1.$ I see two approaches but which are kind of luckily nonsense and unuseful here.

1. We have that
   $$a_{n+ 1}- 1= \frac{1}{2}\left ( a_{n}+ \frac{1}{a_{n}} \right )- 1= \frac{1}{2}\left ( a_{n}- 1 \right )^{2}+ \mathcal{O}\left ( \left ( a_{n}- 1 \right )^{2} \right )\,{\rm as}\,a_{n}\rightarrow 1$$
   We easily find the $\mathcal{o}\left ( n \right )$ but actually I find $\mathcal{o}\left ( n \right )$ to prove that $\lim a_{n}= 1,$ that's a bad idea !
2. From the example * [Estimations of some new recurrence sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021433/822157) *, for the recursion $a_{1}= 1$ and $a_{n+ 1}= \sqrt{a_{n}^{2}+ a_{n}}:$
   $$a_{n}\sim\frac{1}{2}\left ( n+ \frac{1}{n} \right )\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$
   I need to the help to change the problem of the disconvergences to the convergence problem by using $n$ cleverly, I know it's too inconvenient, but I can't think such a better way at all. Thanks for all your nice and valuable comments a real lot !

Comment: Why do you write $\frac{\mathcal{O}(n)}{n}$ instead of $\mathcal{O}(1)$? Do you understand the notion of big-$\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: @Gary, maybe I get it wrong, but let I explain it, what I meant is $\mathcal{O}\left ( n \right )\ll n,$ so $\frac{\mathcal{O}\left ( n \right )}{n}\rightarrow 0\,{\rm as}\,n\in\infty,$ sorry about that.

Comment: You confuse big-$\mathcal{O}$ with little-$o$. Note that the leading term of $a_n$ is $1$ which does not tend to $0$ of course. Study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: I'll notice it.

Comment: @Gary, I didn't write little-o because I wait for for example $n^{1/2}$ in the numerator.

Comment: You can write $a_n  = c + o(1)$ and $o(1)$ can turn out to be for example $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{n})$. (From NN2's answer we actually know what it is, think about it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$a_{n+1}-1 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(a_n-1)^2}{a_n}$$
$$a_{n+1}+1 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(a_n+1)^2}{a_n}$$
Hence
$$\frac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n+1}+1}=\left( \frac{a_{n}-1}{a_{n}+1} \right)^2$$
We deduce that

$$\frac{a_{n}-1}{a_{n}+1} = \left( \frac{a_{1}-1}{a_{1}+1} \right)^{2^{n-1}}$$
or the closed form expression of $a_n$
$$a_n =\frac{1-\left( \frac{a_{1}-1}{a_{1}+1} \right)^{2^{n-1}}}{1+\left( \frac{a_{1}-1}{a_{1}+1} \right)^{2^{n-1}}}$$

Comment: We met again hah