# Find the $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ so that $a_n-1=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, recursion, laurent-series

> Given a recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \dfrac{a_{n}^{2}+ 1}{2}$ with $a_{1}= \dfrac{1}{2}.$ Find the $\mathcal{O}\left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right )$ so that
> $$a_{n}- 1\sim\mathcal{O}\left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right )\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$

*Remark.* By this recurrence sequence, Ji Chen proposed 2 inequalities on AoPS, which I can't prove, of course
$$1- \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{2}{n^{2}}\ln\frac{n}{3}+ \frac{417}{128n^{2}}\leq a_{n}\leq 1- \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{5\ln n+ 3}{n^{2}}$$
and for non-negative $x_{1\div n}$ quite not related
$$\sum_{i= 1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{\left ( 1+ \sum_{j= 1}^{i}x_{j} \right )^{2}}\leq a_{n}^{2}$$
Return to the OP, I realise that
$$a_{n+ 1}- 1= \frac{1}{2}\left ( a_{n}- 1 \right )^{2}+ a_{n}- 1= \frac{1}{2}\left ( a_{n}- 1 \right )^{2}+ \omega\left ( \left ( a_{n}- 1 \right )^{2} \right )$$
As same as what I told on this topic  * [Find the $\mathcal{o}\left(n\right)$ so that $a_n\sim\frac{\mathcal{o}\left(n\right)}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right){\rm as}\lim a_n=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024080/822157) *, I still can't find such an $\mathcal{o}$ satisfying my wish. I need to your help, thanks.

Comment: You are aware that $\frac{\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, aren't you? And that means $a_n-1\sim\frac{\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}$ can't be true, according to Ji Chen's results.

Comment: Copy that, thks

Comment: Now, it's still worse. I'm afraid you should urgently look up the definition of the $\mathcal{O}$ notation.

Comment: This notation makes no sense... instead of (wrongly) using the big-Oh notation here, what you are looking for is simply "the constant $C\neq 0$ such that $a_n-1 \sim C/n$".

Comment: @hd_30102 You want to find more information about the $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ term in the realtion $a_n=1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Note that if you use big-$\mathcal{O}$, you should note use $\sim$ but $=$.

Comment: @Gary $\sim$ (in my comment above) would be the right thing. Both are equivalent: "find $C\neq 0$ such that $a_n = 1+C/n + o(1/n)$" and "find $C\neq 0$ such that $a_n - 1\sim C/n$"

Comment: I think we can develop tp $a_n=1-2/n+ C*\ln(n)/n^2 +...$. But I'm busy now (Valentine's day ;) ). I come back later. ;)

Comment: @ClementC. I was not commenting about your comment. :) They roughly appeared at the same time anyway. I was commenting on the question.

Comment: @Gary oh, my bad. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @hd_30102 This is *not* what this means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @ClementC.sorry

Comment: @hd_30102 May I edit your question to fix the problems with the asymptotic notation?

Comment: It's my pleasure !

Comment: @haidangel Ji Chen proposed 2 inequalities on AoPS. Would you post the AoPS link?

Comment: @RiverLi, here you are * https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h318151p1710542 *, * https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h318104p1710384".

Comment: @haidangel Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have the sequence $a_n$ satisfying $a_{n+1}= \frac{ a_{n}^2+1}{2}$  (1) converges to $1$. Indeed, we have $a_n$ is a increasing sequence ($a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}- 1)^2)$ and the sequence is bounded above by $1$ (we deduce that by proof of induction, as $a_{n+ 1}- 1= \frac{a_{n}^2- 1}{2}<1$ and $a_1 <1$).

Now, with the technique "The second term in asymptotic expansion" of Moubinool OMARJEE provided by RiverLi, we can use the function $f(y)=\frac{1}{1-y}$ for the second order expansion. Indeed, we find this function by noticing that $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}- 1)^2$ and from the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}(y- 1)^2$ we deduce that $x=\frac{2}{1-y}$).

We have

\begin{align}
(1) &\iff 1-a_{n+1} = \frac{ 1-a_{n}^2}{2}\\
& \iff \frac{1}{1-a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1-a_{n}}+\frac{1}{1+a_{n}} \\
& \iff \frac{1}{1-a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{1-a_{n}}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n}} 
\end{align}
then
$$ \frac{1}{1-a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{1-a_{n}}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}\xrightarrow{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{2} $$
or
$$\frac{1}{1-a_{n}} \sim \frac{n}{2} \tag{2}$$

And from (2) we can deduce that
$$a_n \sim 1-\frac{2}{n}$$

Let's denote $a_n=1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n}b_n$, then $b_n = \mathcal{o}(1)$. We have
\begin{align}
(1) &\iff 1-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}((1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{b_n}{n})^2+1) \\
&\iff b_{n+1} =2+\frac{n+1}{2}\left(   2 \frac{-2+b_n}{n} +\left(\frac{-2+b_n}{n} \right)^2 \right) \\
&\iff b_{n+1} = 2+\frac{n+1}{2}\left(   -\frac{4}{n} +\frac{2b_n}{n} +\frac{4}{n^2} -\frac{4b_n}{n^2}+\frac{b_n^2}{n^2}\right)\\
&\iff b_{n+1} = 2+\frac{n+1}{2}\left(   -\frac{4}{n}  +\frac{4}{n^2} \right) +\frac{n+1}{2}\left(  \frac{2b_n}{n}  -\frac{4b_n}{n^2}\right) +\frac{n+1}{2}\left(   \frac{b_n^2}{n^2}\right)\\
&\iff b_{n+1} = \frac{2}{n^2}+(1+\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})b_n + \frac{1}{2n}(1+\frac{1}{n})b_n^2 \\
&\iff b_{n+1} = (1-\frac{1}{n})b_n +\frac{b_n^2}{2n}+ \frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n^2}b_n+\frac{1}{2n^2}b_n^2 \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
We guess that $b_n\sim \alpha \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$, we denote $b_n=\frac{c_n}{n}$. Because $b_n = \mathcal{o}(1)$ then $c_n = \mathcal{o}(\ln(n))$.
\begin{align}
(2) &\iff \frac{c_{n+1}}{n+1} = (1-\frac{1}{n})\frac{c_n}{n} +\frac{b_n^2}{2n}+ \frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n^2}b_n+\frac{1}{2n^2}b_n^2  \\
&\iff c_{n+1}= (1-\frac{1}{n^2})c_n +\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{b_n^2}{2}+ \frac{2(n+1)}{n^2} + (n+1)\left(-\frac{2}{n^2}b_n+\frac{1}{2n^2}b_n^2   \right)  \\
&\iff c_{n+1} -c_n= -\frac{c_n}{n^2} +\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{b_n^2}{2}+ \frac{2(n+1)}{n^2} + (n+1)\left(-\frac{2}{n^2}b_n+\frac{1}{2n^2}b_n^2   \right) \tag{3} \\
\end{align}

We notice that
$$-\frac{c_n}{n^2} = \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n})$$
$$\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{b_n^2}{2} = \mathcal{O^*}(\frac{c_n^2}{n^2})$$
$$\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2} \sim \frac{2}{n}$$
$$(n+1)\left(-\frac{2}{n^2}b_n+\frac{1}{2n^2}b_n^2   \right) = \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n})$$

Hence,
$$(3) \iff c_{n+1} -c_n \sim \frac{2}{n} + \mathcal{O^*}(\frac{c_n^2}{n^2})+ \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n}) \tag{4}$$

Here, if we can prove that
$$b_n^2 = \frac{c_n^2}{n^2} = \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n}) \tag{5}$$
, then
$$(4) \iff c_{n+1} -c_n \sim \frac{2}{n} + \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n})$$
or
$$c_n = 2\ln(n)$$

And
$$b_n = 2\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

**Note:**
I haven't proven yet (5). According to the topic owner, Ji Chen proposed 2 inequalities on AoPS
$$1- \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{2}{n^{2}}\ln\frac{n}{3}+ \frac{417}{128n^{2}}\leq a_{n}\leq 1- \frac{2}{n}+ \frac{5\ln n+ 3}{n^{2}} \tag{6}$$
I guess that directly proving (5) is more difficult than proving the 2 inequalities (6) of Ji Chen.

But if we succeed to prove these 2 inequalities (6), then we can conclude (5) holds true also  (because $2\frac{\ln(n)}{n} +\frac{p}{n^2} \le b_n \le 5\frac{\ln(n)}{n} +\frac{q}{n^2} \implies b_n^2 =  \mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n}) $) and consequently we have the 3rd order expansion of $a_n$ as follows
$$a_n = 1-\frac{2}{n}+2\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $$
And with this expansion, we can deduce a stronger inequality than the second one of (6).

Comment: Of course, ha-ha

Comment: I'll wait for U

Comment: @hd_30102 why accepting it as an answer if it states it's not finished yet?

Comment: The only thing scared me is dealing with $a_{n}$ from the $\mathcal{O},$ he deverses that, now I can replace $a_{n}$ in the XPansion and find it. I'm sure of that he will get in done !

Comment: @NN2 Nice solution (+1 some hours ago). (6) can be proved by Mathematical Induction. I am curious how Ji Chen found the form of (6).

Comment: @RiverLi: I verified for $n=140$ and $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}, a_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2+1) $, the 2 inequalities hold true  $$0.986219 <0.986371 < 0.986559$$

Comment: @NN2 Thanks. But $n=140$ is large. I got new bounds which hold for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @NN2 I think that the following is true (Use Mathematical Induction):
$$1 - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2\ln n}{n^2} + \frac{3\sqrt{\ln n}}{5n(n-1)} \le a_n 
\le 1 - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2\ln n}{n^2} + \frac{3\sqrt{\ln (n + 20)}}{n(n+10)},\  \forall n \ge 3.$$ $a_3 = 89/128$.

Comment: IMO, an $n$ large is not a problem because we can test and obtain results instantaneously with mathematical softwares. Besides, your first inequalities are simpler to be proven.

Comment: @NN2 Yes, I think a rigorous proof is quite complicated.