# Given a recursion $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+1}{2}$ with $a_1=\frac12.$ Prove that $1-a_n\sim\frac2n-\frac{2\ln n}{n^2}\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, recursion

> Given a recursion $a_{n+ 1}= \dfrac{a_{n}^{2}+ 1}{2}$ with $a_{1}= \dfrac{1}{2}.$ Prove that
> $$1- a_{n}\sim\frac{2}{n}- \frac{2\ln n}{n^{2}}\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$
> *Source*: StachMath/@NN2 _ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4025195/822157

I am continuing my research to the asymptotic behaviors, I summarized some idea from my friend @twelve_sakuya to find a proof :

Firstly, we let $b_{n}:= 1- a_{n},$ then we can show inductively that
$$a_{1}= \frac{1}{2}, a_{n+ 1}= \frac{a_{n}^{2}+ 1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\leq a_{n}< 1\Rightarrow b_{1}= \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{b_{n+ 1}}= \frac{1}{b_{n}}- \frac{1}{b_{n}- 2}, 0< b_{n}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$
**Step 1**. Show that $\dfrac{1}{b_{n}}\geq\dfrac{n+ 3}{2}$

*Proof*:
$$b_{n}> 0\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{b_{n}- 2}> \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{b_{n}}= \frac{1}{b_{n- 1}}- \frac{1}{b_{n- 1}- 2}> \frac{1}{b_{n- 1}}+ \frac{1}{2}> \frac{1}{b_{1}}+ \frac{n- 1}{2}= \frac{n+ 3}{2}$$
**Step 2**. Show that $\dfrac{1}{b_{n}}\leq\dfrac{n+ H_{n+ 1}+ \frac{3}{2}}{2}$

*Proof*:
$$\frac{1}{b_{n}}\geq\frac{n+ 3}{2}\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{b_{n}- 2}\leq\frac{n+3}{2\left ( n+ 2 \right )}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{b_{n}}= \frac{1}{b_{n- 1}}- \frac{1}{b_{n- 1}- 2}\leq\frac{1}{b_{n- 1}}+ \frac{n+ 2}{2\left ( n+ 1 \right )}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{b_{1}}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k= 2}^{n}\frac{k+ 2}{k+ 1}= \frac{n+ H_{n+ 1}+ \frac{3}{2}}{2}$$
Because $H_{n}\sim\ln n,$ we speculate that
$$\frac{1}{b_{n}}\leq\frac{n+ H_{n+ 1}+ \frac{3}{2}}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{b_{n}}\geq\frac{n^{2}}{2\left ( n- \ln n \right )}+ \mathcal{O}_{1}\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )\Rightarrow\frac{1}{b_{n}}\leq\frac{n^{2}}{2\left ( n- \ln n \right )}+ \mathcal{O}_{2}\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )$$
He can't continue and we haven't done yet ! I need to the help to complete it ! Thanks for notice me.

Comment: (+1), maybe a nice idea, it's good to see you again here, on MSE, @Haidangel.

Comment: Note that \begin{align*}
b_n  & \ge \frac{2}{{n + H_{n + 1}  + \frac{3}{2}}} \ge \frac{2}{{n + \log n + 3}} = \frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{{1 + \frac{{\log n + 3}}{n}}} \\ &= \frac{2}{n}\left( {1 - \frac{{\log n + 3}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)
 = \frac{2}{n} - \frac{{2\log n}}{{n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)
\end{align*} So it remas to prove the analogous upper bound.

Comment: Thanks a rl lot